# index as an attribute for a function containing data frame

Tags: functions, attributes, index

Two questions. I have created a sample problem, and would be glad to have your help.

I have 2 functions, `fun1` and `fun2`, and one of the function is the attribute of the other function. My function `fun2` works fine as long as `fun1` isn't a function involving a dataframe

```
fun1[i_] := i + 1
fun2[i_] := Module[{x}, x = (Table[i, {k, 1, 2}])]

fun2[fun1[k]]
(*Out[710]= {2, 3}*)
```

Now, lets create a sample dataframe and use it as an attribute:

```
dataset =  Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>, <|"a" -> 2, 
"b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", 
"c" -> {3}|>, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>, <|"a" -> 5,
 "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>, <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", 
"c" -> {}|>}]
```

The output I get is:

```
fun2[dataset[k]]
(*Out[711]={1[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", 
"c" -> {2, 3}|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>, <|"a" -> 4,
 "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", 
"c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>, <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}],  2[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", 
"c" -> {2, 3}|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>, <|"a" -> 4,
 "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", 
"c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>, <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]}*)
```

But, I am expecting more like:

```
Table[dataset[k], {k, 1, 2}]
```

So what might be the problem here?

My second question is, is there any way the `func2` can be written such that it sets the Table index `k` corresponding to the index of `func1[k]`? Say even if I give `fun1[k1]` as an input `func2[fun1[k1]]` still spits out `(*Out[710]= {2, 3}*)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding of the semantics of your situation. You have the list `{1,2}` that you want to treat as a sort of index into other functions. I.e. for some other function `g`, you want a function that will produce `{g[1],g[2]}` and will do this generically with any (appropriately defined) such `g`.

Assuming that's correct, there are built-in constructs that you could use. For example, `Map`:

```
g/@{1,2}
(* {g[1], g[2]} *)
```

Or to use your examples:

```
fun1 /@ {1, 2}
(* {2, 3} *)

dataset /@ {1, 2}
(* gives the first two rows as elements of a list *)
```

You could, of course, define your own function that uses `Map`:

```
fun2[fn_] := fn /@ {1, 2};
fun2[fun1]
(* {2, 3} *)
```